# Configure appspec.yml file for a spring boot application

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

I have deployed a springboot application through codePipeline>Code Deploy. My Appspec.yaml file looks like this:

```
[![version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /build/libs/challenge-0.0.1.jar
    destination: /tmp/
hooks:][1]][1]
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/install_dependencies.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/start_application_v2.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  ValidateService:
    - location: scripts/basic_health_check.sh
      runas: root
```

start_application_v2.sh file looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash

java -jar build/libs/challenge-0.0.1.jar
```

My entire setup is working as required, But the deployment fails with "script timed out" error, because it starts the application with java -jar build/libs/challenge-0.0.1.jar and give the desired results, and hang in there and then after timeout seconds , the results fail.

How to handle this scenario and make the deployment successfull. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does this "java -jar build/libs/challenge-0.0.1.jar" exit within 300 seconds (5 min) - if not you may need to increase the timeout on the 'ApplicationStart ' hook.

Comment: https://youtu.be/TSnlRNuKQ-s

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that java -jar starts your application but never returns that means the deployment will time out. What you could do is run the application in the background

```
java -jar build/libs/challenge-0.0.1.jar >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

That should return instantly so the deployment can continue and won't time out. Please note that stdout also has to be closed that is redirected to dev/null